# How to resolve 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context ' for calendar in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Here's my code:

```
let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.minute, .hour, .firstWeekday, .weekOfYear, .monthSymbols, .year, .second])
```

But I don't know how to solve that warning.

Comment: Actually there are no members `monthSymbols` and `firstWeekday` in `Calendar.Component`

Comment: That's right, thank you